# How do I make the images load after the user zoom in on it, but will not otherwise

Tags: python, image, load

I am building a mosaic, where the user can  insert their own images, but because I don't want to send every user a million images on load and crash their browser, I want to send one whole image(the mosaic), and after they zoom in, the images in that area will load.

I have very limited experience so I have not tried anything yet.

Here's what I currently have:

```py
def GetImages():
    return ImageInfo.query().order(ImageInfo.location).fetch()
class Home(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        defaultdatas()
        homepage = the_jinja_env.get_template('/templates/home.html')
        self.response.write(homepage.render({"images":GetImages()}))
```

```html
<div class="container">
      {%for i in images%}

      <a id={{i.location}} href={{i.url}}>
      <img src={{i.image_url}} alt="image did not load" class="images" >
      </a>

      {% endfor %}
```

I expect the user to see a beautiful mosaic that when zoomed in to a certain amount(say 70%), the images in that area will load.

Edit: This is the demo website I presented : http://inspired-victor-249919.appspot.com/